# How to get the end of a vector and assign it to a string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I want to get the last element of the vector and then assign it to a string but I seem to have problems.

Imagine this vector has already been filled but I do not know how much so I tried to do this.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string s = vec.end();
```

Would a loop work and then just get the last index ?

This did not work so is there a way to get the end of a vector?

EDIT------

```
out.push_back(r.validateR(str));
appendCustomizedOutput = out.back();
DCS_LOG_DEBUG("END " << appendCustomizedOutput);
split(test,appendCustomizedOutput,boost::is_any_of("\n"));
DCS_LOG_DEBUG("END " << test[0]);
```

When i try to print test[0] nothing is printed and i do not know why ?

Comment: we can't really help you, we don't know what's in that string that you are splitting - it has nothing to do with the vector (or it's behaviour) - anyway - this update appears to be a new question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`vector::end()` returns an iterator that is one beyond the last real element in the vector (it's used primarily for checking while iterating).

Best way would be:

```
std::string s = vec.back(); // last item
```

As @JamesKanze and @PeterWood says, don't forget to check for empty vector - else it's undefined behaviour...

Comment: Might be good to mention checking it's not empty `if(!vec.empty())`, otherwise undefined behaviour occurs.

Comment: @PeterWood i have edited the question if you could take a look please

Answer (score 6):

That's what `vec.back()` is for.  Just make sure that the vector isn't empty first.

Answer (score 2):

Use `vec.back()`to get a reference to the last element. Use `vec.pop_back()`to remove the last element (without returning it).

Answer (score 1):

`container.end()` (or whatever kind of container) will return an iterator to the end of the container. To get the last item in the container, you want `container.back()` instead:

```
std::string s = vec.back();
```

Answer (score 1):

`end()` returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container.
You need `back()`: it returns a reference to the last element in the vector container.